# Import .js file natively without using external library

Tags: javascript, scripting

I basically want the equivalent of Java "import" statement in JavaScript.

I am working in a pure JavaScript environment (no HTML).

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) but I don't want to use external libraries like JQuery or RequireJs.

My usecase: I want to import the [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) js validation library

Answer (score 0):

For now, this isn't possible with current ECMA-Script 5.x implementations. For now, you can look forward for the new ECMA-Script 6 (ES-Harmony) standard which provides native module loading without using third-party libraries.

Perhaps you want to download working drafts of next standard [here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) or check some blog post like [this](http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/es6-modules.html) that explains how this is going to work in the near future.

In addition, you can implement what RequireJS has already implemented from scratch in order to avoid adding third-party code to your project, but maybe you can avoid wasting your time re-inventing square wheels and adopt what other have already done!